# OracleDB : trigger on table for checking self-cycle / loops

Tags: java, sql, oracle, triggers

I have this table "function" with a fk to itself (1:N) and I need to check if rows have some bad loops.
My idea is to create a trigger something like this:

```
create or replace trigger FNZ_CHECK_PARENT after insert or update on FUNZIONE
   For Each Row
   Declare
    cnt number;
     Begin
       Select CONNECT_BY_ISCYCLE "is_cycle"
        Into cnt
       From Funzione
        Where Fnz_Parent Is Not Null 
        Connect By Nocycle Prior fnz_id = fnz_parent;

        if cnt > 0
        Then Raise_Application_Error(-20000, 'this is not allowed');
        end if;
    End;
```

but it doesn't with this error:

```
Errore SQL: ORA-04091: La tabella ACCERTA.FUNZIONE è in fase di modifica, il trigger/funzione non può leggerla
ORA-06512: a "ACCERTA.FNZ_CHECK_PARENT", line 4
ORA-04088: errore durante esecuzione del trigger 'ACCERTA.FNZ_CHECK_PARENT'
04091. 00000 -  "table %s.%s is mutating, trigger/function may not see it"
*Cause:    A trigger (or a user defined plsql function that is referenced in
           this statement) attempted to look at (or modify) a table that was
           in the middle of being modified by the statement which fired it.
*Action:   Rewrite the trigger (or function) so it does not read that table.
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: You can't do that since a After trigger will not work to the same table because it will try to find a data that was not commited yet. To do this either you change your logic or change your trigger to BEFORE

Answer (score 1):

A `FOR EACH ROW` trigger can not access the table it is defined on. That's just the way Oracle is.

What you could do is: Insert the row without the trigger, then have an `AFTER STATEMENT` Trigger check for loops.

Alternatively you can use a stored procedure, instead of direct inserts. Of course that only works if you can control the calling side.

Another idea is to create a view and make an 'INSTEAD OF TRIGGER`, although I never tried if it actually works.

Answer (score 0):

This is an attempt to change a mutatable table. Oracle (at least 11.1) does not allow this.
One route can be an autonomous transaction pragma in the trigger. The other one is to implement this logic(whatever it is, since you did not provide example) in a constraint, oracle is capable of that.
In any case your question is ambiguous.